# how to do conditional rendering in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXQUg.jpg)

```
class AppState extends State<App> {
  int counter = 0;
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Center(
            child: Text(if(counter = 0) {
              return 'Hi';
            } else {
              return 'Go';
            }),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              counter += 1;
              name = 'by!';
            });
          },
```

Comment: what is the problem that you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code:

```
Text(counter==0?'hi':'go')
```

Comment: I worked in react native and now switching in flutter I thought  it only work in javascript thanks for your help

Comment: I suggest you do the Dart Language Tour at dart.dev.  Knowing that Dart has "x ? y : z" is pretty fundamental to the language.